# sql server 2008 r2 "Cannot find the object because it does not exist or you do not have permissions"

Tags: sql-server-2008

i want to execute sql command with server name. here is some example query

```
 SELECT * FROM [SYSTEM1\SQLEXPRESS].Sample1.dbo.table1 
 INSERT INTO [SYSTEM1\SQLEXPRESS].Sample1.dbo.table1 values('BALA')
```

the above two executed successfully. in my table1 id filed is auto increment so 
when i execute the following command it return the error message

```
 SET IDENTITY_INSERT [SYSTEM1\SQLEXPRESS].Sample1.dbo.table1 ON
 INSERT INTO [SYSTEM1\SQLEXPRESS].Sample1.dbo.table1 values(2,'KARTHIK')
 SET IDENTITY_INSERT [SYSTEM1\SQLEXPRESS].Sample1.dbo.table1 OFF
```

Cannot find the object [SYSTEM1\SQLEXPRESS].Sample1.dbo.table1 because it does not exist or you do not have permissions. how to solve this problem

Comment: thanks friends. i got the solution from jnk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Looks like this is a known issue with linked servers.](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=97961)  The workaround is:

```
exec [Server-SQL].MyDatabase.dbo.sp_executesql N'SET IDENTITY_INSERT 
Sample1.dbo.table1 ON;
INSERT dbo.table1 values(2,''KARTHIK'');
SET Sample1.dbo.table1 OFF;'
```

Basically run the command as an RPC instead of a direct query.

Comment: The object name '[SYSTEM1\SQLEXPRESS].Sample1.dbo.table1' contains more than the maximum number of prefixes. The maximum is 2.

Comment: @karthik - my bad, remove the server prefix since you are running it local to the linked server.  I'll update.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK you need to execute the command locally. Why don't you create a stored procedure that does this, then the stored procedure can say:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Table1 ON;
```

And you can call the procedure using:

```
EXEC [SYSTEM1\SQLEXPRESS].Sample1.dbo.MyProcedure;
```

Comment: @JNK, I agree. In retrospect, my answer was not helpful at all. Can one downvote one's own answer?

Comment: @Paul - no but you can delete it.